# Why is $xy>0$ not an equivalence relation on the set $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: equivalence-relations

From what I understand, an equivalence relation is a relation which must be

- reflexive
- symmetric
- transitive

The relation in question is:

- reflexive because the square of a number is always positive
- symmetric as $xy=yx$
- transitive as if $xy>0$ and $yz>0$, then $xy^2z>0$. Divide the last expression by $y^2$, and we find that $xz>0$

Comment: @Desperado You should put it in the answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0^2$ is not positive, so the relation is not reflexive.